# Secures requests with the HTTP module

Tags: http, https, module, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

The requests between the application and the server with the [HTTP module of NativeScript](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/http) are they "secured" if the Web site is in HTTP**S**? Otherwise, how make please?

PS: Translated by Google.

Thank you so much.
Excellent day.

Regards,
Benjamin

Comment: This question requires revisiting. Please refer to stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't use HTTPS until you package your certificate with app using this [plugin](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-https).